# How do I plot Linear Regression?

Tags: python, dataframe, anaconda, regression, plotly

I wish to learn how to use Plotly with Python for data analysis.
I have been using [this website](https://plot.ly/scikit-learn/plot-ols/) as reference.

My current code looks like this:

```
from plotly import tools
import plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

py.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

# Create linear regression object
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

# Train the model using the training sets
regr.fit(X_train, y_train)

p1 = go.Scatter(x=X_test, 
                y=y_test, 
                mode='markers',
                marker=dict(color='black')
               )

p2 = go.Scatter(x=X_test, 
                y=regr.predict(X_test),
                mode='lines',
                line=dict(color='blue', width=3)
                )

layout = go.Layout(xaxis=dict(ticks='', showticklabels=False,
                              zeroline=False),
                   yaxis=dict(ticks='', showticklabels=False,
                              zeroline=False),
                   showlegend=False, hovermode='closest')

fig = go.Figure(data=[p1, p2], layout=layout)

py.offline.iplot(fig)
```

However, my output looks like

[image: this]

If I were to follow the website by every line, I would get this:

```
from plotly import tools
import plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

py.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

# Create linear regression object
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

# Train the model using the training sets
regr.fit(X_train, y_train)

def data_to_plotly(x):
    k = []

    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        k.append(x[i][0])

    return k

p1 = go.Scatter(x=data_to_plotly(X_test), 
                y=y_test, 
                mode='markers',
                marker=dict(color='black')
               )

p2 = go.Scatter(x=data_to_plotly(X_test), 
                y=regr.predict(X_test),
                mode='lines',
                line=dict(color='blue', width=3)
                )

layout = go.Layout(xaxis=dict(ticks='', showticklabels=False,
                              zeroline=False),
                   yaxis=dict(ticks='', showticklabels=False,
                              zeroline=False),
                   showlegend=False, hovermode='closest')

fig = go.Figure(data=[p1, p2], layout=layout)

py.offline.iplot(fig)
```

But it would generate the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2656             try:
-> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-5895927e91e2> in <module>
     21     return k
     22 
---> 23 p1 = go.Scatter(x=data_to_plotly(X_test), 
     24                 y=y_test,
     25                 mode='markers',

<ipython-input-84-5895927e91e2> in data_to_plotly(x)
     17 
     18     for i in range(0, len(x)):
---> 19         k.append(x[i][0])
     20 
     21     return k

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2925             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2926                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2927             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2928             if is_integer(indexer):
   2929                 indexer = [indexer]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:
-> 2659                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2660         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2661         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0
```

I'm new to Plotly. How do I fix this?

EDIT:
my X_test looks like this:

[X_test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMqO7.png)

Comment: What does your `X_test` contain?

Comment: X_test contains 25% of values in a dataframe i made with pandas

`gdp=pd.DataFrame(df2_xnan['Explained by: GDP per capita']);
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(gdp, happiness, test_size = 0.25)`

Comment: Can you please print it?

Comment: @MohamedNidabdella

Edited the end of the post to show contents of X_test

Answer (score 4):

I see that `X_train` is a dataframe, Plotly is actually pretty friendly with Pandas, there are several examples in plotly's [pandas example gallery](https://plot.ly/pandas/) so you don't have to deal with in between functions like `data_to_plotly` (that tutorial sadly looks quite outdated). In this case the scatters should look something like

```
p1 = go.Scatter(x=X_test['Explained by: GDP per capita'],
                y=y_test, # Assuming y_test is a numpy array or pandas series
                          # if it is also a dataframe you have to specify the column
                mode='markers',
                marker=dict(color='black')
               )

p2 = go.Scatter(x=X_test['Explained by: GDP per capita'],
                y=regr.predict(X_test),
                mode='lines',
                line=dict(color='blue', width=3)
                )
```